# Trying to access the shopify data using shopifyapi and is throwing an error

Tags: python, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, storefront

I am getting this error when I tried to access the storefront using `shopifyapi` library

> self.endpoint = shopify.ShopifyResource.get_site() + "/graphql.json"
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: `shopify.ShopifyResource.get_site()` is returning `None` and you can't use `+` to sum `None` and `str`.

Comment: I understand that , I do not understand why it is returning none tyoe

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution to this problem was that I still needed to 'activate' the session. Try:

```
session = shopify.Session(shop_url, api_version, password)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)
```

and it should not return None anymore for shopify.ShopifyResource.get_site().

Comment: You are a hero, my dear sir! I was creaking my head over this and answer was obvious